# Changing where my author box is printed

Tags: functions, hooks, actions, the-content

I've got a function in my functions.php that compiles author info for an author box. At the end of the function it `return $content;`

I then have it being added to the end of the content like this

```
// Add our function to the post content filter 
add_action( 'the_content', 'author_info_box' );

// Allow HTML
remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
```

The problem is that instead of having it print out after the content, I need it to print out directly above the comments. I've got some other code that I'm putting into a page template that I want to show up above the author box. And by attaching the author box to the content I can't insert the other code into the template. 
**Edit: The full function code:**

```
function author_info_box( $content ) {

global $post;

// Detect if it is a single post with a post author
if ( is_single() && isset( $post->post_author ) ) {

// Get author's display name 
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );


// Get author's website URL 
$user_website = get_the_author_meta('url', $post->post_author);

// Pass all this info to post content  
$content = $content . '<footer class="author_bio_section" >' . $author_details . '</footer>';
}
return $content;
}

// Add our function to the post content filter 
add_action( 'comment_post', 'author_info_box' );

// Allow HTML in author bio section 
remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the function to echo like this:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

and then in your template, right before the comments template, place the call to your author box function like this:

```
author_info_box();
```

also, you would need to remove the `add_action('the_content', 'author_info_box');`

Full function example:

```
function author_info_box() {

    global $post;

    // Detect if it is a single post with a post author
    if ( isset( $post->post_author ) ) {

    // Get author's display name 
    $display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );


    // Get author's website URL 
    $user_website = get_the_author_meta('url', $post->post_author);

    // Pass all this info to post content  
    $content = '<footer class="author_bio_section" >' . $author_details . '</footer>';

    echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    }
}
```

Note:  `apply_filters` iterates through all the functions that are registered to whatever filter is set (in this case, `the_content`).  Once the last function is done it will return the "filtered" content and thus needing the echo to print it out.

Comment: Does it need to be echo apply_filters or just apply_filters? And where is the $author_output coming from?

Comment: I edited the original post to show you the full function I'm using.

Comment: It needs to have the `echo` and instead of `$author_output` use the `$content`, i've updated my answer with an explanation of `apply_filters`

Comment: Okay, because that's what I tried and its not showing up. Let me look at it again.

Comment: In the post template, what am I supposed to use as an argument for author_info_box();?

Comment: If you are still have trouble, I'd like to see where you put the `author_info_box();` function.

Comment: I put it in single.php -- <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
        <?php author_info_box(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer again, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: The last thing I see is that the variable `$author_details` seems to be coming out of nowhere, you would have to use variables with actual content for anything to show

Comment: I believe that this is now working! I've gone ahead and marked as best answer. I'll keep testing tonight.

Comment: Do I still leave // Allow HTML in author bio section 
remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses'); after the function?

Comment: Not sure why that was in there, its used on the description when creating and updating a user, see documentation here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_description/